# htaccess SetEnv directive is not working in MAMP pro 6

Tags: php, macos, .htaccess, mamp-pro, setenv

I have a solution develop with PHP

1. Framework Phalcon 3.4.5
2. macOS 12.6
3. PHP 7.3.33
4. MAMP Pro 6

I have this .htaccess that is in my root folder:

A SetEnv directive is set like that:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV=development
</IfModule>
```

The right env module are loaded in Apache:

1. mod_env.so
2. mod_setenvif.so

My host config have AllowAoverride All
My AccessFileName is set to htaccess

I use this code in my index file to read the environment variable and I can't get the value.

`defined('ENVIRONMENT') || define('ENVIRONMENT', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));`

`echo ENVIRONMENT . PHP_EOL;`

Considering the SetEnv in the htaccess, should get development has a value, but I keep getting production.

I did test to be sure that mod_env and mod_setenvif are loaded. There is no error in my apache log and php log.

I have no clue why. Any help will be welcome here?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you see the env var in `$_SERVER` by any chance?. You could also try [apache_getenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php)

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file?

Comment: ... the "gotcha" with setting env vars in `.htaccess` is if you have mod_rewrite directives that cause the rewrite engine to "loop" (eg. many front-controller patterns). If this happens then the env var is renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix and it's this _renamed_ env var that gets imported by PHP.

Comment: @MrWhite You're right. I observed the presence of REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENV in the list en variable. I understand why now. Thank you. For the rest, this Phalcon application will be port to Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables set with `SetEnv` in an htaccess file are available in the Apache environment, so you should use `apache_getenv()` or the `$_SERVER` superglobal to access the variable rather than `getenv()`.

You appear to be using SetEnv correctly, and the rest of your setup looks fine.

Perhaps you may be interested in a .env file instead in your root directory, and using [vlucas/dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to load it in, and use Dotenv in your code instead.

Here's an example of using that package:

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

It will look for an .env file in `__DIR__` and load them into your environment, making them available via `getenv()`

Comment: There should be no problem using `getenv()` here. `apache_getenv()` is only available on systems where PHP is installed as an Apache module (and allows access to additional Apache server variables). If the env var is available in the `$_SERVER` superglobal then you should also be able to access it via `getenv()`.